# Unit Tests not Running

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm making a game study in python and I couldn't get unit tests running. It seems packages might be wrong, I'm not sure.

My folder structure is the following:

```
folder/
    src/
      __init__.py
      scenario.py
      monster.py
      ...
    tests/
      __init__.py
      testmonster.py
```

I'm at 'folder' running the following command

```
python -m tests.testmonster.py
```

This is my test class

```
import unittest
from src.scenario import Scene
from src.monster import Zombie
import sys

class TestMonster(unittest.TestCase):

    scene = None

    def setUp(self):
        scene = Scene()

    def testHit(self):
        zombie = Zombie(self.scene, 0,0)

        # we got 1 zombie now
        assertEqual(len(scene.zombies), 1)

        damage = scene.getPlayer().gun.damage

        zombielife = zombie.hp

        numberOfHits = zombielife / damage
        print numberOfHits

unittest.main()
```

When I try to run the file I get

`Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`

Am I missing something ? Is it about the path ? I dindt wish to use VM`s

Comment: Have you tried `self.assert`ing something? ie `self.assertEqual(numberOfHits, 3)`

Comment: Yeah =( Didn't work as well

Comment: why are you running it as `-m` just skip that

Comment: I believe you need to be in your 'tests' folder.

Comment: This first thing I would do is put something like `print 'running'` at the top of the file, and if that prints, move inside the class and then method to see what executes and what does not.

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your setup and was able to repeat what you see. However, if I enter the test folder and drop the '-m', it then works fine for me.

```
python testmonster.py
```

Ran 1 test in 0.000s

Also, I recommend assertpy; [github](https://github.com/ActivisionGameScience/assertpy), I find it more readable than assertions with the standard library.

SteveJ

Comment: Wow, so im missing the packages, maybe something i've missed. I get a "No module named src.scenario" when i do the run you do

Comment: Why is assertpy better?

Comment: @user1767754; readability, eg; "assert_that(1 + 2).is_equal_to(3)". I should have stated that clearly, I'll edit my post.

Comment: @GabrielSlomka; This is another question - but may I offer something that will save you a lot of work in the future. Invest the time to learn virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper (if you are not already using it). Then go to the top level project folder (the one above 'folder' in your case), and run the command "add2virtualenv <folder>". I fought this problem long and hard until I learned the above : )

Comment: i've tryed the above method, "No module named src.scenario".

Comment: oh, will try taking a look at VirtualEnv. Thats a facilitator or a need ?

Comment: @GabrielSlomka; If you are going to be working with Python, I would argue that virtual envs are a need - a soft need maybe, but they make life work so much better, that I no longer code without them. However, you can do the same thing in this case by setting your path - you'll have to research this or ask a different question on SO. Another solution is to use pycharm -- it will run your tests for you.

Comment: I'm checking it out for sure, thanks for the advice ! But i wish to understand the basics of packaging as well. This isnt suposed to work anyway then because of my folder structure ? Thanks alot for your time Steve